# Why Docker Nginx Container Still Showing Defualt Page Instead Of Provided Index File?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have this tree output for a docker project.

```
├── code
│   ├── index.php
│   └── style.css
├── docker-compose.yml
├── mariadb
│   ├── dbs
│   └── Dockerfile
└── nginx
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── lemp.docker.conf
    └── nginx.conf
```

with the conents of nginx Dockerfile & both conf files, I seem to not been able to comprehend where I've done the mistake. Please point it out.

nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENV REFRESHED_AT YYYY-MM-DD
RUN apt-get -yqq update; apt-get -yqq install nginx
ADD lemp.docker.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx CustomSite Conf

```
server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
server_name _;
root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
access_log /var/log/nginx/default_access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/default_error.log;
}
```

nginx Conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
daemon off;
events { }
http {
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

& lastly the compose file

```
nginx:
 image: 'nginx:latest'
 ports:
  - '80:80'
 volumes:
  - ./code/:/var/www/html/
 links:
  - mariadb

mariadb:
 image: 'mariadb:latest'
 ports:
  - '3306:3306'
 volumes:
  - ./mariadb/dbs/:/var/lib/mysql/
 environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root.maria
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's because `default.conf` is still present. You can either re-write it or remove it.

Remove -

```
....
RUN apt-get -yqq update; apt-get -yqq install nginx
RUN  rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD lemp.docker.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
...
```

Re-write -

```
...
RUN apt-get -yqq update; apt-get -yqq install nginx
COPY lemp.docker.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
...
```

Another thing is that you are not using nginx's Dockerfile in you docker compose YML file. So, i don't see your nginx Dockerfile getting utlized anywhere. That might be another issue. Compose file need to looks something as below -

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./code/:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: 'mariadb:latest'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb/dbs/:/var/lib/mysql/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root.maria
```

Comment: Ok Vivek, I updated docker-compose file same as you suggested, but I'm getting this error..

ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
nginx.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string

Comment: Fixed the compose now. There were few formatting issues. Change your Docker file and then try. It's always better to use the normal `docker` commands to build and run before diving into the compose.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because -
You might not have the default.conf file present under `/etc/nginx/conf.d` or you have wrong path setup for `index.html`.

Check the `default.conf` entry for default `index.html` path -

it should be like this -

```
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
```